# SQL: GROUP BY - выбор полей из группы

Tags: sql

Допустим, я имею таблицу:

```
*Identifier* *Date* *Discription*

1 *04.03.2011* 'some text1'

2 *05.03.2011* 'some text2'

1 *06.03.2011* 'some text3'
```

Мне необходимо получить записи сгруппированные по **Identifier**, но чтобы значение поле **Discription** выбиралось исходя из MAX(**Date**).

Т.е. я уже имею:

```
SELECT
  [Identifier],
  MAX([Date]),
  ???
  FROM My_Table
  GROUP BY Identifier
```

Как подтянуть необходимые данные из группы?

Планирую получить результат:

```
1 *06.03.2011* 'some text3'

2 *05.03.2011* 'some text2'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select mt.Identity, Date, Description
from My_Table mt
inner join (
    select Identity, max(Date) as Max_Date
    from My_Table
    group by Identity
) mtg on mt.Identity = mtg.Identity and mt.Date = mtg.Max_Date
```

1. Ещё один вариант решения вопроса можете посмотреть на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column#7745635).
2. И советую исправить грамматические ошибки в названиях колонок :)

Comment: Работает. Спасибо!

Но неужели нельзя просто получить доступ с сформированной из строк группе и выбрать необходимые по условию? Искал, не нашел...

Ведь дело видимо в том, что группировка осуществляется только по выбранным столбцам, но мы же почему то можем получить доступ к **MAX([Date])** используя группировку только по **GROUP BY Identifier**...

Comment: С теми полями, по которым группировки нету, можно производить только какие-нибудь агрегационные действия - max(), min(), avg(), count() и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
SELECT
  [Identiti],
  MAX([Date]) d,
  (select Discription from My_Table t2 where t1.Identiti=t2.Identiti and date = d)
  FROM My_Table t1
  GROUP BY Identiti
```

Comment: Разве так можно? Но идея ясна. Спасибо.

Comment: А проверить?
Это называется коррелирующий подзапрос.

Answer (score 0):

Может

```
    SELECT
  [Identiti]
  FROM My_Table
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
  GROUP BY Identiti
```

Comment: это что-то совсем не то ))